# Rails: soulmate gem pipelining for multiple types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, redis, pipeline

I'm using the [soulmate](https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate) gem for autocompletion in my Rails app, and a big problem I'm encountering is the latency for the query from the client to the Redis server and back.

A quick look at the gem code shows

```
# in lib/soulmate/server.rb#search
types.each do |type|
    matcher = Matcher.new(type)
    results[type] = matcher.matches_for_term(term, :limit => limit)
end
```

As you can see, a new instance of `Soulmate::Matcher` is created for each `type` (i.e., "location", "user", "venue", etc.) and then queries the Redis server using the `matches_for_term` method. That means if I want to query 3 types at a time, there will be 6 handshakes. I want `Soulmate::Matcher` to accept multiple `type`s on creation and pipeline-query the redis server. How would I go about changing the code/overriding? It seems like I need to rewrite the entire gem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the [parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) gem and parallelizing the queries.

It's tacky and still uses way more handshakes than necessary, just in parallel, but it works...for now.